# Summing a column in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This table from Wikipedia shows the 10 biggest box office hits. I can't seem to get the total of the 'worldwide_gross' column. Can someone help? Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
boxoffice_df=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films')
films = boxoffice_df[1]

films.rename(columns = {'Worldwide gross(2020 $)':'worldwide_gross'}, inplace = True)

films.worldwide_gross.sum(axis=0)
```

[image]

This is the output I get when I try calculating the total global earnings:
[image]

Comment: You need to convert the Worldwide gross(2020 $) from a string to a number.

Comment: Looks like that column is a string, not a number. Try `films.worldwide_gross.astype(int).sum(axis=0)`

Comment: Thank you everyone, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to keep only digits in column **worldwide_gross** using `regex` and then convert the column to float using `series.astype('float')`

Add:

```
films.worldwide_gross = films.worldwide_gross.str.replace('\D',"",regex = True).astype(float)
```

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd
boxoffice_df=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films')
films = boxoffice_df[1]

films.rename(columns = {'Worldwide gross(2020 $)':'worldwide_gross'}, inplace = True)
films.worldwide_gross = films.worldwide_gross.str.replace('\D',"",regex = True).astype(float)
films.worldwide_gross.sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
films.astype({"worldwide_gross": int})    
Total =films['worldwide_gross'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Total =films['worldwide_gross'].astype('Int32').sum()
```

or convert data-types 1st.

```
films = films.convert_dtypes()
Total = films['worldwide_gross'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it.

This code will convert the values in the `worldwide_gross` to integers and then sum the column to get the total gross.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_gross(gross_text):
  pos = gross_text.index('$')
  return int(gross_text[pos+1:].replace(',', ''))
  
boxoffice_df=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films')
films = boxoffice_df[1]

films.rename(columns = {'Worldwide gross(2020 $)':'worldwide_gross'}, inplace = True)

films['gross_numeric'] = films['worldwide_gross'].apply(lambda x: get_gross(x))

total_gross = films['gross_numeric'].sum()

print(f'Total gross: ${total_gross}')
```